# Tkinter Image Positioning

Tags: tkinter

Quick and simple question.

I created a Tkinter quiz app and I have 2 pictures. I placed 2 buttons and when I press one, image appears.

The problem appears when I press one button and picture comes up, the other button doesn't do anything... how do I make pictures change?

(this is the code that contains everything needed for the pictures)

```py
img = PhotoImage(file="unknown.png")
panel = Label(master, image=img)

img1 = PhotoImage(file="11232.png")
panel2 = Label(master, image=img1)

----------------------------------

def OpenPic():
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill="both")

def OpenPic2():
    panel2.pack(side = "bottom", fill="both")

def egg():
    global i
    global result
    if i<=len(QueList):
     if v.get() == OutList[i-1]:
         result+=1
     if(i!=len(QueList)):
      que.set("Q."+str(i+1)+" "+(QueList[i]))
      option=OptList[i]
      op1.set(option[0])
      op2.set(option[1])
      op3.set(option[2])
      op4.set(option[3])
     else:
      messagebox.showinfo("Rezultati","Broj pitanja: "+str(len(QueList))+"\nTočno: "+str(result)+"\nNetočno: "+str(len(QueList)-result)+"\nRezultat: "+str((result/(len(QueList))*100))+"%")
      messagebox.showinfo("Result","Tocni odgovori: " + Answers)
    i += 1
Button(master,text="Sljedeće",command=egg,bg="green",fg="white",width="10",font='Helvetica 12').place(x=160,y=200) 
Button(master,text="Slika 1",command=OpenPic,bg="green",fg="white",width="10",font='Helvetica 12').place(x=50,y=200) 
Button(master,text="Slika 2",command=OpenPic2,bg="green",fg="white",width="10",font='Helvetica 12').place(x=270,y=200) 
mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], also you don't need to use `.place` as far as I imagine and also using `.pack()` like that for labels will theoretically place the second one that is getting packed below the first one so that could be the issue and you may need to use `.grid`, (also as mentioned you probably don't need to use `.place` and just in case don't use `*` when importing)

Comment: Of note, you can't create widgets before creating a root window (though this doesn't apply when using the Python shell). Please improve your example code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.